# how to apply ModelCheckpoint in a custom training loop for tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, callback, tensorflow2.0, checkpoint, custom-training

we can set `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()`, then pass a `callbacks` argument to `fit()` method to save the best modelcheckpoint, but how to make the same thing in a custom training loop?

Comment: Please check the details described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#training_loop) to use `checkpoint` in custom training loop.

Answer (score 1):

2. You can use CallbackList:

   ```
    cp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                  monitor='val_loss',
                                  save_weights_only=True,
                                  save_best_only=True,
                                  mode='auto',
                                  save_freq='epoch',
                                  verbose=1)
    callbacks = CallbackList(_callbacks, add_history=True, model=model)
    logs = {}
    callbacks.on_train_begin(logs=logs)

    optimizer = Adam(lr=init_lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, clipvalue=1.0)

    loss_fn = BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    train_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
    val_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
    train_acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
    val_acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

    @tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
    def train_step(x, y):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = self.net(x, training=True)
            loss_value = loss_fn(y, logits)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.net.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.net.trainable_weights))
        train_loss_tracker.update_state(loss_value)
        train_acc_metric.update_state(y, logits)
        return {"train_loss": train_loss_tracker.result(), "train_accuracy": train_acc_metric.result()}

    @tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
    def val_step(x, y):
        val_logits = self.net(x, training=False)
        val_loss = loss_fn(y, val_logits)
        val_loss_tracker.update_state(val_loss)
        val_acc_metric.update_state(y, val_logits)
        return {"val_loss": val_loss_tracker.result(), "val_accuracy": val_acc_metric.result()}

    for epoch in range(args.max_epoch):

        print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
        start_time = time.time()

        for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_gen):

            callbacks.on_batch_begin(step, logs=logs)
            callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step, logs=logs)
            train_dict = train_step(x_batch_train, np.expand_dims(y_batch_train, axis=0))

            logs["train_loss"] = train_dict["train_loss"]

            callbacks.on_train_batch_end(step, logs=logs)
            callbacks.on_batch_end(step, logs=logs)
            if step % 100 == 0:
                print("Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f" % (step, float(logs["train_loss"])))

        train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
        print("Training acc over epoch: %.4f" % (float(train_acc),))
        train_acc_metric.reset_states()
        train_loss_tracker.reset_states()

        for step, (x_batch_val, y_batch_val) in enumerate(val_gen):
            callbacks.on_batch_begin(step, logs=logs)
            callbacks.on_test_batch_begin(step, logs=logs)

            val_step(x_batch_val, np.expand_dims(y_batch_val, axis=0))

            callbacks.on_test_batch_end(step, logs=logs)
            callbacks.on_batch_end(step, logs=logs)

        logs["val_loss"] = val_loss_tracker.result()
        val_acc = val_acc_metric.result()
        print("Validation acc: %.4f" % (float(val_acc),))
        print("Time taken: %.2fs" % (time.time() - start_time)

        val_acc_metric.reset_states()
        val_loss_tracker.reset_states()
        callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs=logs)

    callbacks.on_train_end(logs=logs)
   ```